# Filling matrix with condition python

Tags: python, matlab, for-loop, if-statement

I am converting this matlab code into Python but apparently I am making a small mistake that the results are not the same.  Here is the matlab code:

```
alpha = 0.1;
beta = 0.01;
Dt = 0.001;
N = 1000;
time = 0:Dt:40; 
state = zeros(length(time),N); 
R = rand(length(time)-1,N);

for j = 1:N
    for i = 2:length(time)
        if (state(i-1,j) == 0) 
            if (R(i-1,j) <= alpha*Dt) 
                state(i,j) = 1;
            else
                state(i,j) = 0;
            end;
        else                     
            if (R(i-1,j) <= beta*Dt) 
                state(i,j) = 0;
            else
                state(i,j) = 1;
            end; 
        end;
    end; 
end;
Open_stochastic = sum(state,2)/N; 
open_deterministic = (1-exp(-time*(alpha+beta)))*alpha/(alpha+beta);

plot(time, Open_stochastic, ’k-’, time, Open_deterministic, ’k--’)
```

and here is my python code:

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
%matplotlib inline 

alpha = 0.1
beta = 0.01
Dt = 0.001
N = 1000

time = np.arange(0, 40, Dt)
state = np.zeros((len(time), N))
R = np.random.rand(len(time), N)

for j in range(0, N-1):
    for i in range(1, len(time)-1):
        if state[i-1][j] == 0:
            if R[i-1][j] <= alpha*Dt:
                state[i][j] = 1
            else:
                state[i][j] = 0
            if R[i-1][j] <= beta*Dt:
                state[i][j] = 0
            else:
                state[i][j] = 1

    
open_stochastic = state.sum(1)/N 
plt.plot(time, open_stochastic)
```

the open_stochastic elements are all zero and the plot is just a horizontal line but in matlab code the plot is exponential (See the images)
[image]

[image]

Comment: The statement `state[i][j] == 1` does nothing.  You have too many equal signs there.

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks for your comments and sorry for my sloppy mistake. I corrected my original code but still the results are not the same , please see the images

Comment: You should correct those smart quotes

Comment: @MadPhysicist Can you specify "smart quotes"?

Comment: E.g. `’k-’` -> `'k-'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next problem is that you are missing an `else:` in between the innermost `if/else` pairs.  Also, you should remove the `-1` from both of your `for` statements.  Remember that Python ranges exclude the endpint.  `range(N)` already runs from 0 to N-1.  With those changes, I get something that approaches your desire.
[image]

**Update**

Here is the correct code:

```
...
for j in range(N):
    print(j,end='\r')
    for i in range(1, len(time)):
        if state[i-1][j] == 0:
            if R[i-1][j] <= alpha*Dt:
                state[i][j] = 1
            else:
                state[i][j] = 0
        else:    # <<< this is the line you were missing.
            if R[i-1][j] <= beta*Dt:
                state[i][j] = 0
            else:
                state[i][j] = 1
    
open_stochastic = state.sum(1)/N 
plt.plot(time, open_stochastic)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please post the right answer? I am not sure where I am missing else

Comment: Well, OK, but all I did was a line-by-line comparison of the Matlab and the Python.